# Where should I install Laravel on a shared hosting server?

Tags: laravel, installation, shared-hosting

I have found many questions about this subject but i really got confused and i want to be carefull about this.

Ok so i installed composer in the below dir :

```
/home/antonis/composer/composer.phar
```

Now my accessible `"public_html"` is at :

```
/var/www/html/project_name/index.html
```

So `project_name` is like `public_html` i guess.

Where should i run the `laravel` installation?

Would it work if it was like this :

```
/home/antonis/laravel/app
/home/antonis/laravel/bootstrap
/home/antonis/laravel/config
/home/antonis/laravel/database
```

etc

And the public dir (where `public` files of laravel should be) :

```
/var/www/html/project_name
```

Comment: In my opinion, Laravel *shouldn't* be on a shared server. A VPS runs you $5 on Digital Ocean and gives you vastly better options for setting up the system, including control over things like queues, caching, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes i've read that, but i am really out of options right now so i am trying to make it work like this even if it's not the best option.

Comment: You should just move the Laravel folder outside of public_html (it isnt supposed to be there), and then copy the contents of the public folder to the destination. Finally change the include paths in this index.php, and it should be working. Keep in mind: VPS is always better.

Comment: Is that allowed on a shared hosting server? To use files outside of the public_html?

Comment: @JanWillem Could you check the above comment?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I don't know exactly. Hosting parties may vary in their policy, or even allowance of this. If not allowed, you could copy the Laravel directory to a seperate directory and use htaccess to prohibit access to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the project to public folder then.. **.env** is exposed.

1. All the credentials are exposed
2. Source code is not secure.

Use sub directory installation for laravel 
follow the link

https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install

You should read the article linked Only the public folder should be in the public webspace. Everything else should be private.

**Modify this Lines from Public->index.php**   to the public_html .

```
   require __DIR__.'/../director name/bootstrap/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../your director name/bootstrap/app.php';
```